TypeError: props.signIn is not a function
I'm developing a React application where I've implemented a login form using styled-components and Redux for state management. The login form includes a Google sign-in button (Google styled component) that triggers a Redux action (signInAPI) upon click. However, every time I click the Google sign-in button, I encounter an error:
enter image description here
Code Overview:
Here's a simplified version of my Login.js component:
import styled from "styled-components";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signInAPI } from "../actions";

const Login = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      {/* Navigation and other components */}
      <Google onClick={() => props.signIn()}>
        <img src="images/google.svg" alt="google" />
        Sign in with Google
      </Google>
      {/* Other components */}
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled.div`
  /* Styles for the container */
`;

const Google = styled.button`
  /* Styles for the Google button */
`;

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  signIn: () => dispatch(signInAPI()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);

Error Details:
The error message indicates that props.signIn is not a function when I attempt to invoke it within the onClick handler of the Google button component.
Additional Context:

Redux action signInAPI is defined and imported correctly.
mapDispatchToProps is mapping signInAPI to props.signIn.
Other Redux setup seems to be functioning correctly as per my tests.

Request for Assistance:
I've tried different approaches to resolve this issue, such as checking my Redux setup, verifying action creators, and ensuring correct prop passing. However, I'm still encountering this error consistently. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Can you please provide a console.log of props.

this is the file called actions/index.js and it refers to the function created SignInAPI():'''import { auth, provider } from "../firebase";
export function SignInAPI() {
return (dispatch) => {
auth
.SignInWithPopup(provider)
.then((payload) => {
console.log(payload);
})
.catch((error) => alert(error.message));
};
}
''''
hope it helps.

The issue lies in how you're passing the signIn function as a prop to your Login component. Here's what's happening and how to fix it:
Problem:
connect from react-redux is wrapping your Login component and injecting props through mapDispatchToProps.
mapDispatchToProps maps the signInAPI action to props.signIn. However, connect returns a new component that holds the actual signIn function as a prop, not the original signInAPI.
Instead of mapping the action in mapDispatchToProps, directly pass the signInAPI function as a prop to the connect function:
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { signIn: signInAPI })(Login);

This will make signInAPI available directly as props.signIn in your Login component.

hey I did what you mentioned but the issue still remains the same.
